# Reload Scene Button doesn't work on Unity 5.3 when clicked

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need some help or I think I’m missing something on my script.

I created a GUI Button, created my c# script and attached it to the “Canvas” gameobject.

Then on my button created the On Click() event as you can view it on the following image:

[GUI Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvWU8.jpg)

And here is my script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class RestartLvl : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start () {

    }

    void Update () {

    }

    void OnMouseDown() {
        ReloadCurrentScene();
    }

    public static void ReloadCurrentScene() {

            string sceneName = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name;
            SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName, LoadSceneMode.Single);
    }


}
```

So when I press the button nothing happens, please help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use OnMouseDown() since you are already calling the ReloadCurrentScene() in that button OnClick event.

But the onclick event target has error message, , so you'll to fix that, might work if you just re-select it from that dropdown.

Comment: Removed the OnMouseDown() and reselected from the dropdown, still doesnt work. I see the "Missing" error but dont know what is missing..

Comment: remove static from the method